# custom message ssh "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

Usually I am blocking hosts with **/etc/hosts.deny**.
When restricted host trying to connect to the sshserver user gets following message

```
"ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"
```

Is it possible to customize message?

Answer (score 0):

The message is being generated by your local ssh client, *after* the connection has been dropped. So: no, it's not possible.

However when I see this message I know from experience that it is most likely caused by tcp wrappers (i.e. hosts.deny / hosts.allow).